# Voice to text punctuation and new line in Spanish andorid 5

Tags: android-versions, voice-recognition, text-input

Does Android 5 recognize punctuation and new lines in Spanish voice-to-text?

Answer (score 2):

Only for  `Spanish(Spain)` but not for other variants (for example `Spanish(LatinAmerica)`)

AFAIK the available commands are:

> "coma" (,)
>    "punto" (.)
>    "signo de interrogación" (?)
>    "retorno de carro" o "nueva  linea"  (carriage return)
>    "signo de exclamación" (!)